# Uniqueness of a PDE solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, vector-analysis

Suppose $F:U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ vector field on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the partial differential equation

$$F(x) \cdot \nabla \psi (x) = \lambda \psi (x).$$

Under what conditions is a solution $\psi: U \to \mathbb{C}$ guaranteed to exist? If a solution exists, under what conditions is it unique?

Does the answer admit further refinement under the additional assumptions that $F$ is a [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Complete_vector_fields) vector field and that there is a smooth attractor in $U$ such that all integral curves of $F$ in $U$ asymptotically approach this attractor in positive time?

Comment: Where are you looking for a solution? $\mathcal{C}^1$? $L^2$?

Comment: Also, are we allowed to pose any condition on $F$ and/or $\psi$ on $\partial U$?

Comment: @bartgol When I wrote this question, I had differentiable solutions in mind. However, I'm interested in hearing about other classes of solutions as well. I'm interested in the case in which the boundary of $U$ consists of a union of integral curves of $F$ (i.e. $U$ is an invariant set for the vector field $F$), so $F$ is "tangent" to $U$, but I would like to avoid assuming much about the boundary of $U$. For the application I have in mind, $U$ is the basin of attraction of an attracting periodic orbit of $F$. I believe the boundary of $U$ is generally not smooth in this case.

Comment: @bartgol as for conditions on $\psi$, I didn't have any in mind.

Comment: So $\partial U$ is not smooth. Is it Lipschitz at least?

Comment: If $\partial U$ is Lipschitz, and you can fix $\psi$ on $\partial U$, then there is a unique solution in $H^1(U)$ for $\psi_k$, assuming that either $F$ is divergence free or $\lambda_k+\frac{1}{2}\nabla\cdot F\geq C >0$. Here $\psi_ = \psi_0+i\psi_1$ and $\lambda=\lambda_0+i\lambda_1$.

Comment: I'm hoping to make as few assumptions as possible, but I'm interested in any information. Relaxed assumptions on the boundary of $U$ might be OK. However, the divergence-free case isn't really useful for me (I'm interested in vector fields $F$ which admit an asymptotically stable compact smooth attractor, so the flow of $F$ can't be volume-preserving). Your statements still interest me, though -- Can you point me to any specific references?